# bash - get a list of environment variables with proper handling of new lines

Tags: linux, bash, newline

```
$ export MYVAR=$(echo -e "something\nMYVAR=10")
$ env
...
MYVAR=something
MYVAR=10
...
```

The code above shows the problem.
If you try to read this using simplified version (and lots of people do it this way) you would will get wrong values. This explains it:

```
$ env | while IFS== read var value; do
    [ "$var" == "MYVAR" ] && echo $value
done
someting
10
```

After long investigation I am wondering if `bash` or `sh` is is simply not capable of handling this case.

If I could get just a list of variables without the values I could have it solved but looks like without an external task (python, for example) I can't do it...

**QUESTION**: How, in shell, I can get a list of environment variables with their values that would work with the example above?

Comment: From the output of `env` you can't tell what is an assignment and what is a value, even in python. Use `env -0`.

Comment: @choroba Wrong. In python you can call `for k, v in os.environ.items()` and get them in a proper way. I could then from a script call such script and get the variables but I don't want to. I look for a pure bash solution.

Comment: Using `os.environ` isn't using "the output of `env`" :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As choroba pointed out, you can use `env -0` :

```
export MYVAR="$(echo -e "something\nMYVAR=10")"

env -0 | while IFS== read -d '' -r var value; do
    [ "$var" = "MYVAR" ] && echo "$value"
done
something
MYVAR=10
```

Answer (score 3):

`env` only shows the exported environment.

```
compgen -A variable
```

will give you a list of all environment variables - including the variables not exported.

For each of these you can then run:

```
typeset -p "$@"
```

to get the full declaration.

Or you can get all declarations:

```
typeset -p
```

Comment: Although Philippe gave me exactly what I need but thank you so much. I am "shell" shocked (punt intended.) I have never heard or used these above. Simply wow. Do you happen to know if there is `compgen -A variable` for the exported ones only? Thanks so much!

Comment: `compgen -A export` seems to do just that.

Comment: That is something! Danke!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` to get just the *names* of the environment variables:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {for (k in ENVIRON) { print k }}'
...
```

Since the names are guaranteed to be free of newlines, you can pipe this to your shell loop:

```
awk '...' | while read name; do
   value=${!name}
   ...
done
```

or do your processing in `awk` itself if possible.

(In `bash`, you can use `declare -x` to get output similar to what `env` produces. It would be nice if there was an additional flag you could use to get *only* the names of environment variables.)

Comment: Checking. I was afraid I will have to have something 'extra'. I run in a very thin environment and I may not have access to awk, so I was looking for pure bash/sh/ksh, and I see no solution (so far.)

Comment: I am upping you now in hope I will be able to use awk. I will still wait for someone coming with `env --miracle` option or something like that :D

Comment: Bummer. The thin environment does not have awk. The good part it has python, so I can always use python. Your example gave me the though I can use that method instead of awk. Thank you again!

Comment: Ah, I picked `awk` since it's part of the POSIX spec.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to see an environment variable without its name is to just echo it (inside a quoted string):

```
$ export MYVAR=$(echo -e "something\nMYVAR=10")
$ echo "$MYVAR"
something
MYVAR=10
```

The environment variable contains a newline followed by "MYVAR=", making the output of "env" look a little strange, but it is working correctly.

Comment: The example was used to show the problem. The solution I am looking for is to get a list of environment variables with their values. As you can see you can't get the proper value of MYVAR. I have updated my post to clearly state what is the objective of my question. I hope it is clear now.

In your answer you asked for what is the value of "MYVAR". That is not a problem.